# What the difference between "automatic drive" and "autopilot drive"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I refer to those smart cars that can distinguish traffic light, avoid walkers or some other work demands intelligence.
For these two phase "automatic drive" and "autopilot drive", which is more accurate? and why?

Comment: Fully manual -> automatic gearbox -> cruise control -> traffic-aware adaptive cruise control -> lane departure assistance -> [Tesla Autopilot](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/jul/01/tesla-autopilot-model-s-crash-how-does-it-work) -> driverless car. But the more recent technologies are really just temporary intermediate capabilities that probably won't be relevant for long enough that everyone even knows what they are, let alone agrees on what to *call* them.

Comment: SAE International defines 5 levels of autonomy. Six if you include Level 0 which is no automation.  https://www.sae.org/misc/pdfs/automated_driving.pdf. Autopilot drive is at best marketing words which have no well-defined meaning outside of whatever the marketing department decided they mean. Stick to the SAE levels.

Comment: Thank you. May be I should go to English Language Leaners site.

Answer (score 2):

An [*automatic drive*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/automatic+drive) is often used for a car where only the *transmission* is automatic, i.e. you don't need to manually shift gears.

The phrase *autopilot drive* makes it more clear that the *car* is doing (part of) the driving itself, though if it does not need any input from the human driver at all (apart from specifying the destination), it's often called an [auto*nomous* car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_car).